# Sallen Key filter for audio applications (guitar)

Tags: audio, filter, noise, passive-filter, guitar-pedal

I am building a custom guitar effects pedal.
This is a digital pedal where the microcontroller handles all the effects.
The guitar signal enters the silicon domain through the ADCs , the effect is applied, then the DACs take control to transform it back to the audio world.

Unfortunately, the DACs aren't very good so noise is introduced.
This means i get high frequency noise on my aplifier.
Provided, i do not have a spectrum analyzer to measure the spectral information of the output signal...

What do you think it is a good cutoof frequency, in order to maintain the audio information while cutting off the high frequency noise?

Comment: what's your sample rate? What frequency do you want your audio response to go up to? If the DACs are bad, then no filter will fix that.

Comment: How do you know it's dac noise?

Comment: you do have anti-alias filters on input and output, don't you? What's the bit width of your input and output converters as well?

Comment: The cutoff frequency should be over 20kHz and considerably less than half the sample rate.